# Write row text in file including python keywords?

Tags: python, file

**Source Code:**

```
table_start_value="\begin{table}[ht] \n\begin{center} \n\begin{tabular}{|p{2cm}|p{7cm}|p{2cm}|} \n\hline \n\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{ID}}  \& {\textbf{Title:}}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Priority}}\\ \n\hline\n"

def write_line(inf):
    with open( inf,'w') as fwri:
             fwri.writelines(table_start_value)

file_src="foo.txt"
write_line(file_src)
```

**Problem :**
Why blury text appear in the foo.txt file and how I can write exact text in the file  ?

[image]
**Expected output :**

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|p{2cm}|p{7cm}|p{2cm}|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{ID}}  & {\textbf{Title:}}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Priority}}\\
\hline
```

[image]

Thank you for you suggestion !

Comment: If you're seeing blurry text, that has absolutely nothing to do with the code you've posted. Check your display settings.

Comment: @user2357112 this is not issue with display setting. I attached a two image and you can see the difference

Comment: The line starts with "\b" which is being interpretted as a backspace. Just like "\n" is a newline. If you want a slash, you need to escape the first "\" as "\\". Or you need to escape the whole thing. "\t" is also turning into a tab. Treat the whole thing as a raw string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\t` means `tab` in text so you have to use `\\t`. There are other special chars like `\n`, `\r`, `\b` etc. You have to use `\\` with this chars if you what exact text in file.

You can also use `r` prefix but with triple `"""` and without `\n` and then you don't have to use `\\`

```
table_start_value = r"""\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|p{2cm}|p{7cm}|p{2cm}|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{ID}} & {\textbf{Title:}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Priority}}\\
\hline
"""

def write_line(inf):
    with open( inf,'w') as fwri:
             fwri.writelines(table_start_value)

file_src="foo.txt"
write_line(file_src)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the string line `table_start_value`. You should write it as the following :

```
table_start_value="\\begin{table}[ht] \n\\begin{center} \n\\begin{tabular}{|p{2cm}|p{7cm}|p{2cm}|} \n\\hline \n\\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\\textbf{ID}}  & {\\textbf{Title:}}  & \\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\\textbf{Priority}}\\\\ \n\\hline\n"
```

i.e. adding a "`\`" to every latex command.

Comment: Yes. Should be '\\b' not '\\\b' though.

Answer (score 1):

Many character combinations starting with `\` are special in python. Do this to unmangle your output file:

```
with open( inf,'w') as fwri:
    replaced_string = table_start_value.replace("\b", "\\b").replace("\t", "\\t")
    fwri.writelines(replaced_string)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is with the backslash character: `\`.

In python a backslash (almost) always affects the next character that comes right after it, altering the meaning of that character. You can see this when you use the string `\n` and don't see a literal backslash followed by a literal "n" - instead you see a newline. This is because the backslash alters the meaning of "n" to become a newline instead. But "n" is not the only character that is affected this way.

If you want to store a literal backslash within a string, you need to *backslash the backslash*, like so: `my_string = "Here's a SINGLE backslash: \\"`

For every backslash in your string which you'd like to appear literally, you need to backslash the backslash.

Answer (score 1):

Change your code so that you are using a raw string.

```
table_start_value= r"\begin{tab..
```

Comment: you will have problem with `\n` because it will be written as text `\n` not as newline.